# Filter Multiple Lookup field with Microsoft Graph

Tags: .net, api, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

i am trying to filter a list of item by a Multiple Lookup field.

i have already succesfully filtered the list by a lookup field by using above code :

```
"startswith(Fields/ThemeLookupId%2C+'" + theme + "')"
```

But using this don't work on Multiple Lookup field.

Is there a way to filter Multiple Lookup field ?

Otherwise i will end up selecting all the list and filtering using linq.

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is supported to filter a multi-valued lookup column for a single value.  I have attempted the following and get a 400 Bad Request "Filter not supported" response.

https://graph.microsoft.com/(version)/sites/(site-id)/lists/(list-id)/items?$expand=fields&$filter=(fields/LookupSeason/any(x:x/LookupValue eq 'Summer'))

In my example "LookupSeason" is the lookup column that allows multiple values and each item in list has at least 2 selected.

Comment: You are right, this is not supported. So we have to select all the items and then perform filter.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Graph like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/b57886ef-4c2a-4d56-ad29-27266638ac3b,b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-84a3-f6600fd6cc14/lists/BF55FFA3-3948-4751-B288-6313C91E0AF5/items?expand=fields(select=id)&filter=((fields/lookLookupId eq 71) and (fields/lookLookupId eq 53))
```

Comment: The lookup field contains multiple values. I just want to filter the field that contain multiple values by only one value.